# JButton not enabled after putting border (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {

       JButton button = new JButton();
       Border buttonBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1); // create a line border with the specified color and width
       button.setBorder(buttonBorder); // set the border of this component
       button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
       add(button);

       setVisible(true);
       pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Test t = new Test();
    }
}
```

Basically, if i were to comment out lines 7 and 8 then run the code, the button is clickable. However, if I do put borders, the button becomes dormant and I cannot click it.

Comment: I bet if you add an `ActionListener` to the button, it's still "clickable", but the button is no longer painting the "clicked" state as that is controlled by the UI delegate, but you've overriden those settings by changing the border. If you want the button to appear to be "clicked" you will need to add a listener to the `ButtonModel` and update the state of the button accordingly

Comment: I added an ActionListener to the button and it is clearly working as a button is supposed to; however I am not getting the animation from clicking the button because of the borders. I want to have the border and the animation as well.

Comment: As I said, you've circumvented the "normal" mechanisms used to do this, so you will need to take control, start by adding a `ChangeListener` to the button's `ButtonModel`, which will let you know when the state changes, based on the current state of the model, you can then determine what "appearance" you need to to give the button yourself, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A992484+buttonmodel)

Comment: Alright so I managed to detect the change and determine whether the button is pressed, selected or armed. How do I now create this animation of a button being pressed?

Comment: Change the state of the button to what you want it to be based on the current state of the model

Comment: *"JButton not enabled after putting border.."* Add the button to a panel, set the border to the panel. .. What is the question?

Comment: `button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));` don't do that. The way to change the size of a button is (by layout, which might stretch it to fit available space or) increase the font or icon size, or increase the margin between the content and button edge.